# Finding the integral of $\cos\theta \cdot dt$ in terms of the integral of $\sin\theta \cdot dt$

Tags: integration, integral-equations

I have an integral as follows:

$$\int_0^T \cos\theta\cdot dt = xT$$

where $\theta$ is a function of $t$

I also have,

$$\int_0^T \sin\theta\cdot dt = y$$

I want to solve for $T$.

If the integrals were indefinite, I could have differentiated the second one and gotten $\theta$ as a function of $t$ in terms of $y$. Integrating that would have got me $xT$, but unfortunately, I don't see how I can do that as the integrals are under limits.

I also thought of substituting $\cos\theta$ as $\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}$ and then somehow simplifying so that I get it in terms of the left hand side of the second equation but was unsuccessful.

I am certain it is possible since the second integral is a sine of a function that is common to both integrals, there must be enough information contained in the second equation to completely determine the first integral. I just don't know how to extract it.

How do I go about it? I just learnt integration recently, and I'm not all that familiar with the various techniques.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^T  \dots d\,\theta?$ Or is there a function $\theta(t)$?

Comment: So, you have 2 integrals given, and you have to solve for the upper limit $T$ . Right?

Comment: @gammatester: $\theta$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali: Yes.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ constants?

Comment: Try to use $$\cos x = \cos^2 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \sin^2 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) $$

Comment: @mfl: Yes. Naturally.

Comment: that dt is irritating me... ! Else, it would have been easier.

Comment: This is not answerable for general $\theta(t)$; the function could do literally anything on $[0,T]$. What if $\theta(t)=4\pi Tt$? Then $\cos(\theta(t))$ would look exactly the same as the cosine of a sawtooth function since cosine takes on the same value multiple times. The same holds for sine.  This goes away if $\theta(t)$'s range is within $[0,T\pi]$. It may help to consider that:

$$\int_0^T\cos(\theta(t))dt+i\int_0^T\sin(\theta(t))dt=\int_0^T e^{i\theta(t)}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{[0,T]}(t)e^{i\theta(t)}dt$$ which might be easier to integrate, depending on what $\theta(t)$ is.

Comment: @enthdegree: I actually need this solution for a physics problem. I can tell you that $\theta$ varies continuously from $\pi/2$ at $t=0$ to $0$ at $t=T$. Does that help?

Comment: @Gerard, it might! Does it stay within these bounds?

Comment: @enthdegree: Yes. Always. If you want take a look at the problem, I've posted it on Physics.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121569/finding-the-time-of-convergence-for-this-system-of-particles